# Is it correct to define the F-measure as the harmonic mean of specificity and sensitivity in such a way?

Tags: model-evaluations, metric, definitions

It is common to define the F-measure as a function of precision and recall, as mentioned in [1]:

> $F_{\beta}=\frac{(1+\beta^2)PR}{\beta^2 P+R}$

However I came across some other cases, another definition is used [2] (without weights):

> $F = H(sensitivity, 1- specificity)$

Where H is harmonic mean.

Reference:

1. [F - measure derivation (harmonic mean of precision and recall)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/32035/54250)
2. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-68947-8_133.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52892413/2243842

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one is general formula the other you get for Beta=1:

The beta value **greater** than 1 means we want our model to pay more attention to the model Recall as compared to Precision. On the other, a value of **less** than 1 puts more emphasis on Precision. So you just want to generalise, and punish certain mistakes more.

So to conclude: Correct in mathematical sense is always to generalise and derive special cases, in that sense the first one is preferable since setting beta to one you get the 'standard' F-1-harmonic-mean-formula.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.fbeta_score.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as they are effectively synonyms of one another. See for instance [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity)

If you pay attention, the first formula is the (weighted) harmonic mean of the recall and precision.